# Can a user change the input variable of a select box?

Tags: php, html

I would like to secure user input, if it is text input we can simply use `filter_input` and `mysql_real_escape_string`.

My question is: Do I have to use those when variables are coming from a select box? Is it possible for some crafty user to change POST values from the browser?

My select box is populated dynamically from a database. Do I still have to compare recevied data (after submit) with the database, and use `mysql_real_escape_string` for safety?

Comment: And yes, it is easy to send different data than "yours" via POST, so always validate user input.

Comment: And switch to prepared statements, this is 2012.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, you need to confirm **all** data you get from the client, always.

Answer (score 2):

Yes someone can alter input on any form element. Something as easy as FireBug in firefox will allow me to alter any source code on my client copy of a webpage and submit a form with my altered data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trust **anything** that comes from the user. Assume everything a user sends you is evil. You need to escape everything or even better use prepared statements / parametrized queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate each input if you want a secured site.
You need to check if the select box field matches with your database values for surety.